# Gradient in a Checker Texture's individual cells

Tags: procedural

[image: Like this one]

How can I add a gradient in a Checker Texture's individual cells procedurally?
My goal is to create a procedural carbon fiber material.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a good start :

[image]

Make sure to match the Mapping node scale to the checker texture scale. You'll need to adapt the mapping nodes as well as the Modulos plugs depending on the orientation and the face you need to display on.

Comment: You could use a value node to make sure the scales are always in sync

Comment: How do you plug a value node to a specific scale axis of a mapping node ?

Comment: Value -> Combine XYZ -> Scale

Comment: what scale now ?

Comment: Ah silly me, I didn't realize the Mapping node has no connections for its values. My bad.